# Kevin path at neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to discover how many hops I have to do to know a friend with Cipher. I have these relationships.

```
(Gutierrez)-[:Conhece]->(Felipe),
(Felipe)-[:Conhece]->(Gutierrez),
(Felipe)-[:Conhece]->(Fernando),
(Fernando)-[:Conhece]->(Felipe),
(Fernando)-[:Conhece]->(Pedro),
(Pedro)-[:Conhece]->(Fernando),
(Pedro)-[:Conhece]->(Arthur),
(Arthur)-[:Conhece]->(Pedro),
(Arthur)-[:Conhece]->(Vitor),
(Vitor)-[:Conhece]->(Arthur),
```

and when I execute my query it shows Fernando. What I want is to show only Vitor, Pedro and Arthur.

```
MATCH (n:Leitor)-[r:Conhece]-m
WHERE n.nome='Pedro' OR m.nome='Vitor'
RETURN n,r,m
```

[image]

with my Bacon Path query ->
[image]

Comment: what is exactly what you are trying to query? i mean, you provided the answer you want, but you didnt explain your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm adding another answer because I think I understand what you want and it's different than my other answer.

If you want to find everybody that both Pedro and Vitor have met (in this case, just Author):

```
MATCH (pedro:Leitor)-[:Conhece]-(in_common:Leitor)-[:Conhece]-(vitor:Leitor)
WHERE pedro.nome='Pedro' AND vitor.nome='Vitor'
RETURN in_common
```

That also might look a bit better like this:

```
MATCH (pedro:Leitor {nome: 'Pedro'})-[:Conhece]-(in_common:Leitor)-[:Conhece]-(vitor:Leitor {name: 'Vitor'})
RETURN in_common
```

I also notice from your screenshots that every meeting has two relationships.  That may very well be what you want, but if your plan was to always have two relationships whenever two people meet then you can get away with just one relationship.  When you query bidirectionally (that is, without specifying direction like in the queries above) then you'll get relationships in either direction.

Normally you only want relationships going in both directions if the direction is important.  That could be because your just recording that it goes from one node to another, or it could be because you're storing different values on the relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
MATCH shortestPath((n:Leitor)-[rels:Conhece*]-m)
WHERE n.nome IN ['Pedro', 'Vitor']
RETURN n,rels,m,length(rels)
```

In this case `rels` will be a collection of relationships because the path is variable length.  You can also do:

```
MATCH path=shortestPath((n:Leitor)-[rels:Conhece*]-m)
WHERE n.nome IN ['Pedro', 'Vitor']
RETURN n,rels,m,length(rels),path,length(path)
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the answer. But the result is still showing all people. It should show only Pedro, Vitor and Arthur.

Comment: Did you mean to have both `n` and `m` in your `WHERE` clause?  What are you trying to query for?  If you are trying to find all people who know "Pedro" or "Vitor", then should "Fernando" be included as well?  Do you care about direction?

Comment: Hi Brian, I upload 2 images from my first query and the second that I want to take of Fernando from my results. Because to Pedro meet Vitor, he just need to know Arthur

Comment: I see from the screenshots your whole graph and I see the result of your initial query, but I don't know what it is that you want from a query....  What are you trying to find?

Comment: I have to find that to Pedro meet Vitor, both need to meet Arthur, but just  Arthur